# combining 2 images For accessory View

Tags: iphone

I have 2 images which I want to join side by side and show in accessory view.

```
 CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 20, 20);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"homesmall.png"] drawInRect:imageRect];
    CGRect imageRect1 = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20, 20);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"update.png"] drawInRect:imageRect1];

    UIImageView *statusImageView = (UIImageView *) cell.accessoryView;

    statusImageView.image= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I am trying to put both the images side by side but somehow nothing in coming in accessory view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cell accessoryView] is UIView, not UIImageView. And I don't get why do you draw your images since you have them in the bundle.

Why not:

```
UIImageView * image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"homesmall.png"]];
UIImageView * image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"update.png"]];

[image1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
[image2 setFrame:CGRectMake(20,0,20,20)];

UIView * cellAcc = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40,40)];

[cellAcc addSubview:image1];
[cellAcc addSubview:image2];

[cell setAccessoryView:cellAcc];

[image1 release];
[image2 release];
[cellAcc release];
```

Comment: I am getting warning saying that UIVIEW may not respond to addSubview on the line where we are addding subviews of image 1 and image2.